# Why wouldn't the following program compile?

Tags: c++, variables

Why wouldn't the following code compile? Basically what is not right in the following code? I'm assuming that declaring the same variable twice without assigning any value would be the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; int foo() { return 1; }
int main() { int a; int a; cout << foo() << endl; return 0;}
```

Comment: Why don't you try deleting the second variable declaration and seeing if it will compile (hint, yes it will)

Comment: You have declared `a` twice.

Comment: I thought so. It's actually a midterm question and I don't have any IDEs right now to test so I just wanted to make sure. Thanks!  @Justin

Comment: Then Minus 10 points for your Professor's House, for asking stupid questions on the mid-term!

Answer (score 1):

remove one "int a;" declaration. Even if it was possible, there is no reason to do that.